# Getting weird error while using html in IOS

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

While implementing a web-view into the page I coded like the following

```
 _testURLString = @"http://192.168.4.196/course/Course";
NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                       <html><head>\
                       <style type=\"text/css\">\
                       body {\
                       background-color: transparent;\
                       color: blue;\
                       }\
                       </style>\
                       </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                       <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                       width=\"400\" height=\"700\"></embed>\
                       </body></html>"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, _testURLString, 400, 700];

UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:videoView];
```

The warning X-code through is more '%' conversions than data arguments warning at the

src=\"%@\"

I don't know what to do please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `stringWithFormat:` , and this method was supposed to replace `src=\"%@\"` for another string, but you are not passing none.

It should be something like this:

```
NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                   <html><head>\
                   <style type=\"text/css\">\
                   body {\
                   background-color: transparent;\
                   color: blue;\
                   }\
                   </style>\
                   </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                   <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                   width=\"400\" height=\"700\"></embed>\
                   </body></html>", _testURLString]; //or something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `width=\"400\" height=\"700\"` to `width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\"` since you're passing the arguments later in the build up of your HTML String.

Also, as 0x7fffffff said, if you're just making a simple string then write your `embedHTML` as `@"your_string"` instead of `[NSString stringWithString:@"your_string"];` XCode nowadays warns for this redundancy.

Comment: can you type in the exact warning ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass src `(src=\"%@\")` value in this string. For more info see in last line

```
 NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                           <html><head>\
                           <style type=\"text/css\">\
                           body {\
                           background-color: transparent;\
                           color: blue;\
                           }\
                           </style>\
                           </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                           <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                           width=\"400\" height=\"700\"></embed>\
                           </body></html>",_testURLString];     // Edited
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the second formatted string entirely seeing as it didn't actually do anything of value. Additionally, you never added format specifiers for the URL and the width/height of the video in the initial formatted string. Here's an example:

```
NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                       <html><head>\
                       <style type=\"text/css\">\
                       body {\
                       background-color: transparent;\
                       color: blue;\
                       }\
                       </style>\
                       </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                       <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                       width=\"%i\" height=\"%i\"></embed>\
                       </body></html>",_testURLString,400,700];
```